# AWS Lambda - Fixing a bug

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Let's say my service is live in production using AWS Lambda in place? Now, I find that there is a bug in AWS Lambda, say I fix it and update lambda function, will some messages during the update would fail? How does it handle it internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages would continue going to the old version until the new version is fully deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Since Lambda is distributed and stateless, no messages will be lost. Depending on the size of your Lambda function, it may take a few seconds for AWS to deploy, but it won't be accepting requests until it is ready to do so (has uploaded and validated successfully).

Worst case scenario, the moment you push the update, there may be several seconds where your Lambda is accepting requests on your old version.